# Decoding Packet preamble success percent

Tags: signal-analysis

I have a radio that stays on a channel for 500 milliseconds to listen to the packets and increment the detection_counter if packet is found( by correlating the preamble which is about 48us)

For some reason, radio goes to OFF state (multiple times) during the 500ms period (to deal with other higher priority tasks) and at the end of 500 ms , I have the counter which tells

1. how many times radio went off (lets say radio went off 80 times )
2. total duration of radio went off (i.e. combined off duration is 120 milliseconds)

Since the radio may go off randomly ,Is there any way I can estimate the probability of preamble not getting decoded (given the information) and using the probability to estimate the detection_counter ?

Comment: Yes there is, if you make some assumptions about when the radio goes off and for how long -- worst-case is probably periodically every 6.25ms, for 1.5ms each time.  Then assume a uniformly distributed start time for your preamble and find the probability that it overlaps with one of the "radio off" times.  **BUT** if your radio is subject to being turned off and on like this, you're probably not working in an environment where it'll be viable.  You may find that it's better to spend your effort on fixing the underlying problem.